# How can I remove a contact from the "favorites" page of the phone app?

Tags: contacts, calls

The Phone app has a "favorite" page (the title is a star) which contains the contacts you most frequently/recently(or whatever...) called:

[image: The most important contacts page according to the Phone app]

I find the contacts that appear there quite irrelevant and even dangerous (e.g. I recently blocked a contact and it still shows up there because said contact continuously called me)

My question is: how do I remove a contact from said page? The menu does not contain any option to remove them, moreover the contacts are *not* starred in the contact app.

Comment: Hold the contact in the favorites page, drag & drop it on '*Remove*'.

Comment: @acejavelin Note: "the contacts are not starred in the contact app".

Comment: @GokulNC Oh gosh... that interaction is really unexpected & it also feels really weird. Thank you anyway, please post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hold the contact in the favorites page.
2. Drag and drop it on `Remove`.

(This may vary for different phone apps. The method above works on AOSP stock phone app)